# The page isn’t redirecting properly Openshift

Tags: redirect, dns, openshift

I have an open shift account and I created an application a little while ago for which I didn't add a domain. Now i am trying to add the domain its not working correctly.

The domain is **www.quantumfreedom.com**. There is a CNAME in place for both www and * pointing to the application on openshift. I have submitted a ticket on GoDaddy and with my other domain provider and they both say it's a hosting issue and not a domain or DNS issue.

The full message reads as follows:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>     Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>     this address in a way that will never complete.
>     This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
>     cookies.

This is not the only domain I have an issue with before with open shift.

Comment: Your DNS does look OK, check Openshift settings

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more please @DusanBajic ?

Answer (score 0):

Current `CNAME` record for `www.quantumfreedom.com` looks like [this](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#CNAME/www.quantumfreedom.com):

```
;QUESTION
www.quantumfreedom.com. IN CNAME
;ANSWER
www.quantumfreedom.com. 3548 IN CNAME vitscript-james1vince.rhcloud.com.
```

If http://vitscript-james1vince.rhcloud.com is the site you want to show to the  users who type http://www.quantumfreedom.com in their address bar, then as far as DNS is concerned, there is nothing more you can or should do, users will be directed to the correct IP address.

Now you need to make sure that once the request for `www.quantumfreedom.com` arrives at your http server, the server responds with correct content. At the moment that is not the case, if you try from command line:

```
curl -v http://www.quantumfreedom.com/
```

Notice these two lines in response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
< Location: http://www.quantumfreedom.com/
```

This means that webserver is redirecting the client back to the same url, causing an infinite loop, resulting in browser error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

(or similar, depending on the browser)

This redirect can com from either webserver settings (Apache `.conf` or `.htaccess` files) or even application itself, so those would be the places to look next.

Comment: There is nothing in the .htaccess because there isn't one. Now the apace.conf I don't know because that's not accessible on a Paas such as OpenShift for obvious reasons.

Comment: This is not the only domain i have had an issue with whilst using Openshift. Openshift lists StackOverflow as it's official support pages lol. But the CNAME is set up according to their specs and the add a domain is set up on the Opeshift side correctly, i was hoping an Openshift team member could address this.